# Move the Joomla! module layout override to a different tab

Tags: module-display, module-params

Is there a way to either move the Joomla! module layout override option which is usually found in advanced?  If not, is there a way to ensure that it is the same as one that I put in my regular window?

It seems an odd workflow to choose the layout there for some modules but I'd also like to take action depending on which module is chosen.

I still want to use /tmpl so I prefer to use the standard Joomla! way of doing things although I am aware I can just create a new XML field and use the tmpl file by calling with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am losing you a little bit in your question.

Saying move the Joomla module layout override option, do you mean to display that field within another tab?

If so, what's the problem you are facing in placing it inside you other tab? Assuming we are talking about a custom module you developed, then simply, place the field's xml declaration in your other fieldset.

---

I am also losing you on your other question:

> If not, is there a way to ensure that it is the same as one that I put
>   in my regular window?

What is "the same" as "which one" you put in which "your regular window"?

as, well let me frankly admit that the remaining part of your question doesn't make much sense to me either.

So if all your question is, is how to display the module's layout field in another tab, then the answer is given above, otherwise please clarify.

Comment: I think you have answered my question.  Just move it to the other tab and that will work.  That seems like the sort of thing I could have tried myself really :)  The second query was if I create an XML field in the main tab for the same purpose, can they mirror each other.  But there's no need if I can just move it.  Thanks.  You're a godsend.  I must owe you several beers by now.  If you're ever in London come to Joomla! London User Group and I'll buy you some.